# How to use the ODBC 64 bit to read the excel file in Windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: excel, jakarta-ee, jdbc, odbc

> I need to read the excel file through ODBC 64 bit in my windows 7 64
>   bit machine.

By default in my system there are two odbcad32

1. [32-bit] C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32
   (**It contains the microsoft excel driver**)
2. [64-bit] C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32 (**It doesn't have the
   microsoft excel driver**)

Since, the system doesn't have the Microsoft Excel Driver in the 64 bit ODBC, I downloaded the AccessDatabaseEngine_x64 and installed it.

After the successful installation under

[64-bit] C:\Windows\System32\odbcad32 the *Microsoft Excel Driver* is present.

*Now when I run the java program through eclipse. An error message is displayed like*

**No suitable driver found for jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/ashokkumarg/Desktop/Excel/TestCaseData.xls**

But the same code works very well in the Windows 32 bit machine. I dont know what could be the cause.

**Java version**

*Windows 7 32 bit Machine (where the code works)* **1.7.0_51**

*Windows 7 64 bit Machine (where the code fails)* **1.8.0_31**

**CODE**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class ConnectionTest {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {

Connection c = null;
Statement stmnt = null;


System.out.println("Test case is started Running");
try{


c = DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:/Users/ashokkumarg/Desktop/Excel/TestCaseData.xls");

stmnt = c.createStatement();
String query = "select * from [TestCase$];";
ResultSet rs = stmnt.executeQuery( query );

while( rs.next() )
{
System.out.println( rs.getString( "Page" ));
}
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

> I have few questions over here:

1. When two odbcad32 is present, How to read the excel file using ODBC 64 bit in Windows 7 64 bit machine.
2. While running the program whether it is taking the 32 bit odbcad32 driver details. If so how do I need to configure the ODBC 64 bit drivers to use it in the program.

Comment: Have your application display `System.getProperty("java.version")` and [edit] your question with the results from both machines (the one that works and the one that doesn't).

Comment: @GordThompson I have edited the question with the results from both the machines. Kindly go through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `System.getProperty("java.version")` is returning "1.8.xxxx" then that machine is running Java 8 and the JDBC-ODBC Bridge is not available because it has been removed from Java 8.

If you want your application to use ODBC then you will have to make sure that your users are running Java 7 or earlier. This might be difficult if you don't directly manage their machines because the automatic update feature of the Java runtime (JRE) now distributes Java 8.

If you want your application to be able to run under Java 8 then you will have to use some other way of accessing the Excel data. [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org) would be one possibility.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply Gord. Now I have installed the Java version 7 in my Windows 7 64 bit machine. When I run the code it says like **"[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"**

Comment: I have given the registry permission access to the ODBC keys also.

Comment: You need to have your app display `System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model")` and verify that the "bitness" of the JVM is the same as the "bitness" of the version of the Access Database Engine that is installed on that machine (both 64-bit or both 32-bit).

Comment: Yes, the JVM and the Microsoft Access Database Engine which is installed in the 64-bit machine is 64 bit only.
But in the 32-bit machine I haven't installed the Microsoft Access Database Engine itself.
But Still how come the Microsoft Drivers are present in odbcad32.exe(32 bit machine). Do the Microsoft Access Database Engine is needed to install the Microsoft Excel Drivers(.xls) or something else is needed ?

Comment: It is working now, I changed a little thing in code and that made to work the code well. 
**c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};DBQ= "path";**

If I'm missing something or proceeding wrongly just divert me.
Thank you very much for your effort Gord..

Answer (score 0):

As you are saying that the same code works fine on a 32bit machine, I guess your application is also 32bit?

Note: The bitness of the driver does not depend on the operating system, but on the application trying to use that driver.

So: If you have a 32bit application you will need to use the 32bit ODBC-Administration tool to configure a DSN entry and you need the corresponding 32bit ODBC-driver.

If your application is 64bit you need to use the 64bit version of the administration tools and also the 64bit driver.

So if your Java runtime is a 32bit runtime you need to always use the 32bit version of the driver. If you use a 64bit java runtime you will need to use the 64bit version of the driver.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. Here I have few clarifications.
Actually I'm using 64 bit Java run time as well as 64 bit eclipse luna.
But by default in my Windows 7 64 bit machine 32 bit ODBC is installed.
Then I manually installed the 64 bit ODBC driver. As you mentioned like it should be a 64 bit series or 32 bit series.

But when I run the code, how could it point to the 32 bit ODBC driver, when the 64 bit ODBC driver is installed.

Do I need configure any thing in the eclipse settings or in my system settings.

Comment: I would first check that the application if it is running from withing eclipse is really running as 64bit. For that I would take ProcessExplorer ( https://technet.microsoft.com/de-ch/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx ), from there select the corresponding java-Process, then right click -> Properties, and there in the Tab 'Image' check the value of 'Image'.

Comment: Yes, I have checked for the eclipse application the Image value is 64-bit only.

Comment: Also, the ODBC drivers will be automatically invoked when I run the program in Eclipse application. 
In the process explorer, I'm unable to find out whether the ODBC 32-bit is running or ODBC 64-bit is running.

When I run the both ODBC drivers 32-bit as well as 64-bit manually, In process explorer the image value is n/a for both of the drivers.